# what's better way to store master_username and master_password in terraform rds configuration?

Tags: amazon-rds, terraform

I need help on what's the better way to store the master_password in https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/rds_cluster.html. Currently I masked with XXX before commit to the github. Could you please advise a better way to store this? Thanks

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
  cluster_identifier      = "aurora-cluster-demo"
  engine                  = "aurora-mysql"
  availability_zones      = ["us-west-2a", "us-west-2b", "us-west-2c"]
  database_name           = "mydb"
  master_username         = "foo"
  master_password         = "bar"
  backup_retention_period = 5
  preferred_backup_window = "07:00-09:00"
}
```

Comment: one option is to use a private repository. you would have the password stored in cleartext which is less than ideal. an other option is to have this file automatically generated on the server, and it would fetch the password from a local file that is obviously not in github)

Comment: Typically you'd deploy this stuff via CI process. Which often allows you to store secrets and pass them into your deployment process without revealing what the contents are to the end user. Otherwise, if not possible, utilise variables and pass in via environment variables.

Comment: it is the best sample for the new aws `secrets manager` to mange the rds password, but I don't think this service is available in terraform currently

Answer (score 1):

Preferable you use AWS Secrets Manager and not store any sensitive data in the state file at all (even though your state file might be encrypted, it's a good practice to avoid such implementations).

Here I've created a *secrets.tf* that's responsible for generating a random password and storing it in AWS Secrets Manager.

```
resource "random_password" "master"{
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "_!%^"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "password" {
  name = "${var.environment}-${var.service_name}-primary-cluster-password"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "password" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.password.id
  secret_string = random_password.master.result
}
```

Now to get the data during the tf apply, I use a data provider (this gets data from AWS on the fly during the apply):

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "password" {
  name = "${var.environment}-${var.service_name}-primary-cluster-password"

}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "password" {
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.password.id
}
```

I then reference them in my Aurora cluster as following:

```
resource "aws_rds_global_cluster" "main" {
  global_cluster_identifier = "${var.environment}-${var.service_name}-global-cluster"
  engine                    = "aurora"
  engine_version            = "5.6.mysql_aurora.1.22.2"
  database_name             = "${var.environment}-${var.service_name}-global-cluster"
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "primary" {
  provider                  = aws
  engine                    = aws_rds_global_cluster.main.engine
  engine_version            = aws_rds_global_cluster.main.engine_version
  cluster_identifier        = "${var.environment}-${var.service_name}-primary-cluster"
  master_username           = "dbadmin"
  master_password           = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.password
  database_name             = "example_db"
  global_cluster_identifier = aws_rds_global_cluster.main.id
  db_subnet_group_name      = "default"
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: The `aws_secretsmanager_secret_version` data source stores the secret value in the Terraform state file in plaintext, but at least it's not in the Terraform script.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out John, you're right!

Answer (score 1):

Since AWS Provider version 5.8.0, there is a new attribute called `manage_master_user_password`, which is used as an alternative to `secret`. I switched to the newer approach because I discovered that after provisioning the infra, the root password was not aligning with the secret stored in Secrets Manager, even though it was working perfectly fine in version 4.0.0 of the provider (I did an upgrade of the provider). With the new approach, I confirmed that after resources were creating and visited the RDS Console, the "Manage master credentials in AWS Secrets Manager” selection was checked and a corresponding secret was automatically created in Secrets Manager without even needing to provision the secrets manager resource directly. There is also a `master_user_secret` block to specify options for the secret.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

(anyway, you can't hide the password its *.tfstate file, you should save the tfstate files in s3 with encrypted)

```
terraform plan --var-file master_username=xxxx --var-file master_password=xxxx
```

So your tf file can define them as variables.

```
variable "master_username" {}
variable "master_password" {}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
  cluster_identifier      = "aurora-cluster-demo"
  engine                  = "aurora-mysql"
  availability_zones      = ["us-west-2a", "us-west-2b", "us-west-2c"]
  database_name           = "mydb"
  master_username         = "${var.master_username}"
  master_password         = "${var.master_password}"
  backup_retention_period = 5
  preferred_backup_window = "07:00-09:00"
}
```

When run `terraform plan/apply` with CI/CD pipeline, I used to put the passwords to s3 (encrypted) or SSM (now you can put in aws secrets manager). So write a wrapper script to get these key/value first and feed to terraform command.